# Copy database using MongoDB 3.0 Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm trying to copy a database from a remote host running MongoDB v3.2 to a local one running MongoDB v3.0 using the MongoDB Java Driver 3.0.

Using the shell, I'm easily achieving this by running:

```
db.copyDatabase("test", "test1", "104.xx.xx.21:27017", "admin", "xxxx")
```

The Java driver doesn't seem to have a [`copyDatabase`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/#copydatabase-access-control) command, however the [`MongoDatabase`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase.html) interface has a [`runCommand`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase.html#runCommand-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) method, so I thought of using the DB command [copydb](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/copydb/). But... this command is [only able to authenticate](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/copydb/#authentication-to-source-mongod-instance) on the remote host using MONGODB-CR, while MongoDB v3.0 and higher [forces me](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/security-mongodb-cr/#mongodb-cr-and-scram-sha-1) to create users with the SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism.

My final thought was to invoke the shell command using the driver but apparently that's only possible using the deprecated [`DB`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/DB.html#doEval-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) class and is not encouraged in new code...

So what options do I have?

Answer (score -1):

It works for me.

```
DB adminDB = mongo.getDB("admin");
DBObject cmdObj = new BasicDBObject("copydb", 1).append("fromhost", "localhost").append("fromdb", source).append("todb", destination);
CommandResult commandResult = adminDB.command(cmdObj);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However this is the old version of the driver (i.e. not v3.0). I am looking for a way to do it with v3.0.